# How can I edit vba in excel that closes the application on open?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook_Open sub that does some stuff and then calls application.quit. However, now that I have added this, how I can edit the routine given that excel closes right after it opens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To temporarily bypass the `Workbook_Open` sub hold down shift when you open the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

tools->options->security->macros and change the securiy level to be prompted before macros are executed.